# Phoenix Elixir with JaSerializer

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

ja_serializer 0.10.0, Elixir 1.4, Phoenix 1.2.1

I'm having difficulty trying to embedded data in the attributes for a view hierarchy.

Here's what I have:

```
defmodule MyApp.SomeView do
  use MyApp.Web, :view

  attributes ~w(details)a

  has_one :details,
      include: true,
      serializer: MyApp.DetailsView

  def details(params_here) do
    ...
  end 
  ...
end

defmodule MyApp.DetailsView do
  use MyApp.Web, :view

  attributes ~w(thing)a

  has_one :thing,
       serializer: MyApp.Details.ThingView,
       include: true
end

defmodule MyApp.Details.ThingView do
  use MyApp.Web, :view

  attributes ~w(summary)a

  has_one :summary,
      serializer: MyApp.Details.Thing.SummaryView,
      include: true
end

defmodule MyApp.Details.Thing.SummaryView do
  use MyApp.Web, :view

  attributes ~w(completed_at coordinates)a

  def coordinates(model, _) do
    %{lat: model.y, lng: model.x}
  end
end
```

Expected output:

```
"attributes": {
  "details": {
    "thing": {
      "summary": {
        "completed-at": ....
        "coordinates": {
          "lat": ...
          "lng": ...
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Actual output:

```
"attributes": {
  "details": {
    "thing": {
      "summary": {
        "completed-at": ....
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm wondering if the "details" function in the "MyApp.SomeView" module should be further modified instead of the has_one relationships to get the desired result? Are the has_one relationships only for side loading the relationships in the includes?

Edit: I also removed the has relationships and tried to do this strickly in the attribute function via

```
def details(details) do
  thing = details.thing
  summary = thing.summary
  coordinates = %{lat: summary.coordinates.x, lng: summary.coordinates.y}
  summary =  Map.merge(summary, %{coordinates: coordinates})
  thing = Map.merge(thing, %{summary: summary})

  Map.merge(details, %{thing: thing})
end
```

What am I missing?

Comment: So does your new attempt work?

Comment: No, I get the same output. The coordinates are not serialized.

Comment: That's strange if only `coordinates` is missing. Is your function even being called?

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that details is invoked.

Comment: Nvm, guys apparently we had a custom formatter embedded in our lib that was overriding all my settings. Case solved!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't seem relevant to other users as the resolution was unrelated to the details of the question.